# Split a tuple into n parts

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a function that receives a range of doubles (Double, Double) and an n (Int), where I divide this interval into n equal parts. I know that if it was a list, I did a Split in the list, but being in tuples and getting Doubles, I'm not sure what to do.
Thank you for any help

Comment: Why would that make a difference? If you have `[1,2]` and `3`, then you can not simply use `split` to obtain 3 tuples...

Comment: I assume the two double are the lower/upper bound. Then it is possible to compute `n` equal output ranges. But w/o further information one can only assume what the actual question is.

Comment: yes, let's say I get a range of a, b, and n = 4, I want that in the end to yield 4 tuples containing each interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to @mschmidt's answer, but I think a list comprehension is probably clearest:

```
intervals :: Int -> (Double,Double) -> [(Double,Double)]
intervals n (a,b) =
  let n' = fromIntegral n
      d = (b - a) / n'
  in [(a + i*d, a + (i+1)*d) | i <- [0..n'-1]]
```

giving:

```
> intervals 4 (1,10)
[(1.0,3.25),(3.25,5.5),(5.5,7.75),(7.75,10.0)]
>
```

If the duplicate calculation of the endpoint offends you, you could write:

```
intervals' :: Int -> (Double,Double) -> [(Double,Double)]
intervals' n (a,b) =
  let n' = fromIntegral n
      d = (b - a) / n'
      x = [a + i*d | i <- [0..n']]
  in zip x (tail x)
```

Note that `zip x (tail x)` is a pretty standard way to get tuples of consecutive pairs of a list:

```
> let x = [1,2,3,4] in zip x (tail x)
[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]
>
```

Comment: thanks ! Just a question, and if instead of giving : Int -> (Double,Double) -> [(Double,Double)] , (Double,Double) -> Int -> (Double,Double) ?

Comment: I'm not sure what a function with this alternative signature (returning only one tuple) is supposed to do.  Can you given an example of how it would be called and what it should return?

Comment: lets say : intervls :: (Double,double)  - > Int -> [(Double,Double)]

Comment: In that case, all you need to do is write `intervals (a,b) n` instead of `intervals n (a,b)` at the beginning of the definition.

Comment: I know,but when i do it,in the solution that you gave me,it does not work.

Comment: At the begginning i was using the last exemple you gave, with zip,but it was not nothing,thanks again for this.

Answer (score 1):

A rough sketch, probably not the most elegant solution:

- Take the two input doubles (I call them `l` and `u`) and compute the width of the input range/interval.
- You want to compute `n` output ranges of equal width `w`. Compute this `w` by dividing the input width by `n`.
- Build a list of length `n` containing the values `l+0*w`, `l+1*w`, `l+2*w`, ...
- Build the list of output tuples by combining the first two items in the list into a tuple. Drop one element of the list. Continue until only one element remains.
- Try to catch all possible errors

Comment: thanks ! Like you said :Build a list of length n containing the values l+0*w, l+1*w, l+2*w , how do i make the condition to stop on this case ?

Comment: Write a recursive function that has an integer argument that starts with `n` and gets decremented in each recursion step. If 0 is reached stop, otherwise do your work and continue the recursion.